gorm: migrate from string to pq.StringArray doesn't work
I have now:
type tableA struct {
    fieldA string
}

and I want to change from a single text to an array of text:
type tableA struct {
    fieldA pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]"`
}

but when a run
Automigrate(&tableA{})

It doesn't change from "text" to "_text".
If I drop table and create it works fine.
I have postgres database.

AutoMigrate command generally only makes non-destructive changes to your current schema. This means it wont automatically drop or modify existing columns to ensure you dont lose data accidentally..   you have to use alter table command
